# Cron expression - every X minutes with exact start date

Tags: cronexpression

Is it possible to run a **single** cron expression that will execute the job every 30 minutes, starting at 9AM tomorrow for example? (from tomorrow at 9 i need it to run forever every 30 minutes). Is that possible? If not, is it possible to do this without date, only start hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will run a Perl script every 30 minutes indefinitely:

```
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/perl /path-to-file/file.pl
```

According to [the top answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576482/perl-cron-scheduler-start-at-x-time-execute-every-y-minutes-forever?rq=1), there is no syntax that enables perpetual running with a specific start time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the thing is, i need a start time for this interval, i don't want it to start immediately.

Comment: @axelrod: I updated my answer to reference another Stack Overflow question similar to yours.